# Check for duplicate row and UPDATE the status keeping the first data unchanged

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Example of my table:

```
Table_1

+-----id-----+-----zone-----+-----address-----+-----status-----+
=============+==============+=================+================+
     1              5                10               ok
     2              2                 8               ok
     3              3                 2               ok  
     4              2                 5               ok
     5              3                 2               ok 
     6              5                10               ok     
     7              3                 2               ok
```

I need to check the duplicate entries *[zone/address combination]* and have the table like this:

```
Table_1

+-----id-----+-----zone-----+-----address-----+-----status-----+
=============+==============+=================+================+
     1              5                10               ok
     2              2                 8               ok
     3              3                 2               ok  
     4              2                 5               ok
     5              3                 2               duplicate 
     6              5                10               duplicate 
     7              3                 2               duplicate
```

The query should check the duplicate combination of zone, address and should update the 'status' column. 
I need to keep the first duplicate data status unchanged and the rest of the repeated data should be marked as 'duplicate'?

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
update
  Table_1 t1 inner join Table_1 t2
  on t1.zone=t2.zone
     and t1.address=t2.address
     and t1.id>t2.id
set t1.status='duplicate'
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work.

```
update table_1 set status = 'duplicate' 
where exists 
select 1 from table_1 t 
where id != t.id
and zone = t.zone
and address = t.address
and t.status = 'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two step

```
# set all duplicate rows as "duplicate"
UPDATE Table_1 t1,(SELECT DISTINCT _t1.id,_t1.zone,_t1.address 
                   FROM Table_1 _t1 
                   INNER JOIN Table_1 _t2
                         ON (_t1.address= _t2.address AND _t1.zone = _t2.zone AND _t1.id != _t2.id) 
                   ) t2 
SET t1.status = 'duplicate' WHERE t2.id = t1.id;
```

and

```
# set status = "ok" to the first row with status duplicate 
UPDATE Table_1 t1, (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(_t1.id) AS id FROM Table_1 _t1 
                     WHERE status = "duplicate" 
                     GROUP BY CONCAT(_t1.zone,"|",_t1.address)) t2 
SET t1.status = "ok" WHERE t2.id = t1.id
```